# use resource file in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, uwp-xaml

I tried to use Resources files (**.resw**) for multi-language.

On the project's root folder, I now have :

```
.\Strings\fr-FR\Resources.resw
&
.\Strings\en-US\Resources.resw
```

On both files, I just have

```
 NAME          VALUE
Welcome       Welcome !
```

and So, I tried to call this reference into a XAML file, but the **TextBlock** stays empty

```
<TextBlock  Text="" x:Uid="Welcome"  MinWidth="200" Height="20" />
```

If the Text is set manualy, it appears, but here, nothing appears.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the name in the string of your resw-file should be Welcome.Text, because you are setting the text property of the textblock.

Then:

```
<TextBlock  x:Uid="Welcome"  MinWidth="200" Height="20" />
```